# RestSharp library sending list objects

Tags: c#, api

I have problem with sending list to api using RestSharp library.

```
public class MedicalExaminationSend
{
    public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public List<TestClass> TestModel { get; set; }
}
```

and I have client method

```
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            foreach (var item in examination.Files)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Path))
                    request.AddFile("Files", item.Path);
            }
            request.AddObject(examination);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```

But in api TestModel list is empty. If i added as parameters

```
foreach(var item in TestModel)
{
   request.AddParameter("TestModel",item)
}
```

In api list TestModel has only one element(first).
How I can send list using multipart (because i also sending files)?

Answer (score 1):

I changed list to array and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know RestSharp - but did you already try to set the testModel data via AddParameter (e.g. as List, or put them in an array first)?

```
request.AddParameter("TestModel",TestModel)
```

What is the result in that case?

Comment: I checked. Also is empty